# Build a js project with package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've two js projects for say A and B, In the Project A's packge.json I've following scripts

```
 "scripts": {
"start": "webpack-dev-server --https --content-base dist/",
"doc": "n-clean docs && jsdoc --package package.json -c 
 ./jsdoc.config.json",
"clean": "n-clean dist",
"build:dev": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
"build:prod": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --env.production",
"build": "npm run clean && npm run build:dev && npm run build:prod && npm run doc"
```

}

when I run npm run build , I got  a bundle js in dist folder of project A.

In B's project , I've the following package.json for scripts.

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"serve": "grunt serve --port=9090 --https=true",
"build": "grunt build --production=true"
```

}

So I can build project B by running npm run build. But can I build Project B after building Poject A(ie it should create bundle in A's dist folder),with in Project B's package.json by adding commands like 
"build":"npm run build ../A" along with project B's build. So Please help me how to achieve this.

Comment: I hope you are having a task named build. In that only you have to write your login.
It will be great if you can share that file too.

Comment: I can suggest you to pass a output dir parameter form project B build, And in task you can check use that using process module.

Comment: consider the script you are using in package.json of B project as a bash script in its directory. Therefore, you can totally run a npm run for package.json of A project if your script works in bash script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can absolutely build Project B's files into Project A's `dist` folder.

You'll have to modify your webpack's config file, it is typically called `webpack.config.js`

In Project B's `webpack.config` file, you'll have to tell webpack the output path.  You can do so by adding this line of code:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '<Path to Project A dist folder>')
  }
};
```

Hope this helps!

Edit in response to building Project A in Project B:

Yes, you'll need to modify your Project B's webpack.config.js file.

You can define multiple entry points in that file as

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    ProjectA: './path/to/my/entry/fileA.js',
    ProjectB: './path/to/my/entry/fileB.js',
  }
};
```

Likely you can copy the entry point from your ProjectA's webpack.config.js file into Project B's.

Comment: okay thank you , is there any way to build Project A, by running  Prjoject B's pakcage.json and webpack.config.js. ie. If I run npm run build in project B, that should build Project A . I used following command in Project B's package.json under script tag."build": "npm run build../A && grunt build --production=true". when I run this  it didn't work for me.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to modify your Project B's webpack.config.js file.

You can define multiple entry points in that file as 

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    ProjectA: './path/to/my/entry/fileA.js',
    ProjectB: './path/to/my/entry/fileB.js',
  }
};

Likely you can copy the entry point from your ProjectA's webpack.config.js file into Project B's.